# How do I get a Scope value in LIferay

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have the following call in a portlet MVC class in liferay:

```
ResourcePermissionServiceUtil.addResourcePermission(
    themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId(), 
    themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), 
    FileEntry.class.getName(), 
    ??, //scope int value... how do I get this?? 
    Long.toString( fileEntry.getPrimaryKey()),                          
    RoleServiceUtil.getRole(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), "Guest").getPrimaryKey(), 
    ActionKeys.VIEW);
```

I would like to know how to get the scope value.  Preferably a global scope value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you have to use `ResourceConstants.SCOPE_INDIVIDUAL`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ResourceConstants in liferay.

```
ResourceConstants.SCOPE_COMPANY
```

There are other scopes of course but that is the object that houses the constants.